# Remove one level of nested arrays from JS data structure

Tags: javascript

How can I convert the following data structure:

```
var data = [ [ { time: 1, speed : 20 } ] ];
```

to

```
var data = [ { time: 1, speed: 54 } ];
```

I just want to remove the array.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the data is an array, you just want to select the first element of the outer array

so the solution would be

```
var data = [[{time:1,speed:20}]]; // Or whatever the data is
data = data[0];
```

Or if you're accessing the data via another object

```
var data = yourObject[0];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
JSON.stringify(data).substr(1,JSON.stringify(data).length-2);
```

Comment: i wanted to remove the `{` and `}` from the object and this was a valid solution