# Create certain JSON form

Tags: php, json

**The form I require is:**

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

**What I get with this php code:**

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
require 'connect.inc.php';
$mysql = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name");
$name = isset($_POST['query']) ? $_POST['query'] : "";


$sql = "SELECT MedicineName, MedicineID FROM medicinetypes WHERE MedicineName LIKE '%$name%'";

$res = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);
$res = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$reply = array();
$reply['suggestions'][]=$res;
echo json_encode($reply);
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

**is this:**

```
{"suggestions":[[{"MedicineName":"Amoxil 500","MedicineID":"1"},{"MedicineName":"Panadol","MedicineID":"2"},{"MedicineName":"Farmako3","MedicineID":"3"},{"MedicineName":"Beer","MedicineID":"4"},{"MedicineName":"Farmako4","MedicineID":"5"},{"MedicineName":"hjkki","MedicineID":"61"},{"MedicineName":"Amoxil 1","MedicineID":"577"},{"MedicineName":"Amoxil 502","MedicineID":"580"},{"MedicineName":"Amoxil 56","MedicineID":"582"},{"MedicineName":"Amoxil 600","MedicineID":"583"},{"MedicineName":"\u03b5\u03bb\u03b1 \u03bc\u03bf\u03c5 \u03bd\u03c4\u03b5","MedicineID":"586"}]]}
```

That extra [ is causing a problem since it's not in the format I need. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Here's a solution that other user posted:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678355/remove-extra-square-bracket-from-json

Comment: @guillefix — That's for hacking around the problem when the JSON is parsed (assuming it is being parsed in JS). The question is asking about fixing the data at source.

Comment: `MedicineName !== value`   and `MedicineID !==data`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

> ```
> $reply['suggestions'][]=$res;
> ```

1. Gets `$reply['suggestions']`
2. Assigns an empty array to if it one doesn't already exist there
3. Puts `$res` (already an array) as the next item in that array

You just want to put `$res` as the value of `$reply['suggestions']`.

Remove the `[]`.

```
$reply['suggestions']=$res;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `$reply['suggestions'][]=$res;` to `$reply['suggestions']=$res;`