# How to merge a multiple array structure from one array into one group of arrays? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm sure this is a dumb question but I'm really struggling with the syntax for this. In javascript I have this:

```
  const arr = [
[
  {
    test: "hey1",
  },
  
],
[
  {
    test: "hey2",
  },
  
],

]
```

This prints out like this:

```
 Array(2)
0: [{…}]
1: [{…}]
```

So accessing it right now is like this `arr[0][1].test`  where i just want to be able to access the other arrays in the array like `arr[1].test`

Hope that makes sense and once again sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: You're looking for the [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you just want to remove one level of nested array. Easiest way would be to just enter the array level into a new array.

```
var newArray = arr[0];
```

You can also refer to this. [Remove one level of nested arrays from JS data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678355/remove-one-level-of-nested-arrays-from-js-data-structure)

Comment: *You can also refer to this* , it's just a link that goes to this page again tho

Comment: thanks for correcting that, I have pasted the wrong link. here's the reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678355/remove-one-level-of-nested-arrays-from-js-data-structure. also updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to unite all the arrays you have into one array

open a new array variable

```
allArr=[]
```

And run in a loop on the old array by using Spread Operato

```
for (let i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
    allArr.push([...i])

    //OR
    
    allArr= [...allArr,...i]
    
}
```

Comment: Since the question is declaring an arr variable, so we don't need to run this looping logic and merge those. We can simply change the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As  *Emiel Zuurbier* mentioned in the comments - you can simply use flat method:

```
const arr = [
[
  {
    test: "hey1",
  },
  
],
[
  {
    test: "hey2",
  },
  
],
].flat();
```

And now this will be your new arr:

[image]

Now you can access your element like this:

```
console.log(arr[0].test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the internal square brackets just like this

```
[
  {Test: 1},
  {Test: 2}
]
```